# Exercise of indentation of C code

Tags: c, bash, indentation

I am trying to improve the indentation of [this C code](http://www.zoology.ubc.ca/~matthey/sfs_code.c). I am not picky as to the exact rules used for indentation, I just care that it looks like something more or less standard!

Interestingly, the code looks good on my browser but once downloaded it is clear that the indentation is caused by a mixture of "tabs" and "spaces" and it looks ugly on both SublimeText2 and TextWrangler.

I tried

```
indent file.c
```

but it returns a long series of error that seem related to the presence counterslash followed by newline ("\\n" or "\\\n" if the slash needs to be escaped) within strings. So I tried to remove those with

```
tr "\\\n" " " < file.c > newfile.c
```

but I did not quite reach my goal.

Comment: `it looks ugly` Set your editor to use tab-size `8` for that file, and it will look better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I download the file, it has CRLF (DOS or Windows style) line endings.  When you run that through Unix `indent`, it doesn't like the backslashes followed by CR instead of NL (aka LF).  If you replace the CRLF line endings, it should be formattable by `indent`.

The problem is that `indent` expects the backslashes to be followed by a newline, but CR is not a newline.

If you have a `dos2unix` or `dtou` command, use that.  If not, use `tr`:

```
tr -d '\015' < sfs_code.c > x31; mv x31 sfs_code.c
```

You can also improve things by replacing the tabs with 8 spaces.  Again, there may be other tools that can do the job, but the classic tool is `pr`:

```
pr -e8 -l1 -t sfs_code.c > x31; mv x31 sfs_code.c
```

The backslash newline sequences for splitting strings over multiple lines is very 1980s-style coding.  Since the C89/C90 standard introduced string concatenation, it isn't necessary (though it is still recognized as legitimate C).

At 6781 lines, that's a pretty big file.  It includes a number of other source files (`.c` extensions) and some headers.  I poked at it with `uncrustify` which had no problem with it; after removing the CR characters, `indent` was fine with it too.

(I used my own `ule` — Uniform Line Endings — program to do the conversion.  It's one of a lot of different possible techniques.)

Note that your `tr` command failed because it mapped both backslash and newline to blank (and left the CR characters unchanged), which is not what you want.  The `tr` command maps single characters; it is not appropriate for mapping combinations of characters as you wanted and needed.

Comment: It's much better now! Thank you +1